# Best way to password protect a dropbox file

Tags: android, dropbox

I adding a Dropbox interface to my android messaging app.  Thanks to responders on another thread I'm using the Chooser SDK to allow my users select to the dropbox file URL to include in a message.

Now I need to make it as easy as possible for them to apply a password to the droopbox file.

The research I have done so far tells me that one way for users to apply password protection to a Dropbox file is by using Passdropit.com.  I have tested it both from my Windows 7 desktop and from my android phone and it works both places.  But this is something they would have to do separately, ahead of time before they composed the message in my app.

Are there any Android/Dropbox APIs that would allow me to apply a password from my code?  If not, is passdropit.com the only tool to do the job?
Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropbox Pro accounts [can now](https://blog.dropbox.com/2014/08/introducing-more-powerful-dropbox-pro/) [apply passwords to shared links](https://www.dropbox.com/help/5887) directly on Dropbox, but this isn't currently exposed via the Dropbox Chooser API (or other Dropbox API). I'll be sure to pass this along as a request though.

That being the case, you would either need to use a third party tool such as passdropit.com, if it allows external integration like this, or replicate the functionality yourself.